# How can I "clean up" branches locally, without breaking everything for others?

Tags: git, branch

I'm pulling changes from someone else's repository (let's call them 'gitnoob' for cathartic reasons) that has stuff all intermingled. They were apparently working in their main branch for everything at first and then learned about branches. It looks a bit like this:

```
                  d - f <--- stuff
                 /   /
A - b - 1 - c - 2 - E <--- dev
```

The numbers are commits that should have been in another branch, and may break things if I merge them into my own `dev` branch. (I'll pull them from `upstream/dev` later -- `upstream` being our shared parent repository -- once they're merged in there.) The lowercase letters are commits that should be part of `stuff`, and the uppercase ones are commits legitimately merged in to `dev`.

Ideally, I'd like to clean this up on my end -- to have something like this locally:

```
  b - c - d - f <--- stuff
 /           /
A --------- E <--- dev
```

Now, `stuff` having all the `stuff`-related changes is going to happen anyway, because `gitnoob/stuff` will also include all the differences between `upstream/dev` and `gitnoob/dev` to that point (and the legitimate `dev` ones will already be in my `dev` branch). The problem is, that means `stuff` will also have commits `1` and `2`, which may well break things.

I need to be able to pull changes from `gitnoob/stuff` without massive amounts of hassle (and, if at all possible, without getting 1 and 2 back in there till they show up upstream), and have them pull changes from me without anything on their end getting reverted or deleted.

How do I do this? Or am I just stuck with 1 and 2 in `stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want a private version of `stuff` that reverts `1` and `2`, but your own public version of `stuff` that still includes it for gitnoob to pull from.  There's no seamless way to do that, but one way to accomplish it is by introducing a couple new branches:

```
...d-f <---stuff-upstream
      \
       g <---reverted-stuff
        \
         h <---my-stuff
```

What you do is make a `reverted-stuff` branch that reverts `1` and `2`.  When you want to make changes that are shared with gitnoob, you branch from `reverted-stuff` to make `my-stuff`.  Change and commit as normal on `my-stuff`.  You should be able to merge your `dev` into `my-stuff` as well.

When you're ready to share the changes, rebase `my-stuff` back onto `stuff-upstream` using `git rebase --onto stuff-upstream reverted-stuff my-stuff`.  That will remove your reverts in `g` and make it look like `my-stuff` was branched directly from `stuff-upstream`, allowing gitnoob to pull without fear.

When you pull from gitnoob, pull into `stuff-upstream`, then merge it down into `reverted-stuff`.  That merge will automatically reapply `g`, where you reverted `1` and `2`.  Then you can branch a new `my-stuff` off of `reverted-stuff`.

That being said, if `1` and `2` are really as problematic as you say, you will be doing gitnoob a favor by getting it out of his branch as well.  If it's not that bad, there's really no reason to go through all this.

Comment: I'd be happy to get them out of his branch as well, if it wouldn't break upstream/dev later (if `1` and `2` are *legitimately* merged in before `stuff` is).  You might be right about it not being worth it; this time around it'd be easier to just say "don't merge `stuff` til 1, 2, and 3 are merged" and get a cattle prod for next time.

Comment: +1 for coming up with the branching thing.  I think we're just gonna do the synchronization thing this time, though.

Answer (score 1):

In that situation, I'd recommend to leave the past as it is and try to do it better in the future.

What's the benefit of taking `b` and `c` out of `dev` and having them only in `stuff`? Since `stuff` was branched off `dev` after `c`, the commits are contained in `stuff` anyway.

I'm tempted to do such things occasionally too but usually I end up thinking *so what?* This is especially the case for those commits made when I learned Git and switched over from SVN. Something went wrong. Okay. But it works. So don't touch it.

Version control is a tool, not an end in itself. You put some code in your repo. That's the precious thing. Not the – maybe – *intermingled* history of the repo.

You could fix the branches locally, but when it comes to merging things back from upstream or pushing changes there, you'll get in trouble.